L'chatchila Ariber: what does it mean and where does it come from?
There seems to be a famous saying from the Rebbe Maharash, Rabbi Shmuel Schneersohn (1834 - 1882):

די וועלט זאגט, אז מ'קען ניט ארונטער דארף מען אריבער, און איך האלט אז
מ'דארף לכתחילה אריבער
The world says that if you can’t go underneath, you must go over. But I say that you should go over to begin with.

The Lubavitcher Rebbe often quotes this, for example in Igros Kodesh (here).
What does "L'chatchila Ariber" means, where does it come from, and what is the lesson we are meant to take from it according to the (Chabad) Rebbeim?

BTW, this is a niggun, or perhaps the inspiration for a niggun in Chabad by the same name (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EW6cTS2XrV8&pp=ygUSbGVjaGF0Y2hpbGEgYXJpYmVy).

I just googled "L'chatchila Ariber" and found https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2718066/jewish/What-Does-Lchatchila-Ariber-Mean.htm .

@AvrohomYitzchok Thanks. But what is the original source from the Rebbe Maharash and what are the foundational sources of it? Is it based on a statement of Chazal etc..

If there appears to be a wall; deny its existence and walk through it as if it did not exist. Its an attitude thing. Accomplish your goals in serving H' by realizing there are no obstacles, just illusions. Therefore nothing is hard to do because difficulties are illusions.

As a starting point see here:

This idea of leaping over obstacles from the very beginning became a symbol of what the Rebbe called a Baal Shem’ske behavior, akin to the conduct of the Baal Shem Tov. It means rising above challenges, never letting obstacles deter you from your path.
There’s a famous story about the Besht, who instructed his students to collect icicles from the roof and then lit them like candles. This was a play on words in Yiddish, in which icicles are called אייז ליכטעלעך = Ice candles. He did this to illustrate the concept of leaping over. The world may say that icicles cannot burn like candles, but the Besht showed that with faith, even seemingly impossible things can be achieved.
In life, people often say we must work within the confines of the world, to be realistic and avoid risks. But the Rebbe teaches us to rise above, to take risks, because we are not limited by the constraints of the world. This attitude leads to success beyond limitations.
The Rebbe loved this idea and encouraged his followers to embrace it.


Shkoyach Dov. Do you know where the original source of the story of the אייז ליכטעלעך can be found?

@Shmuel - I haven't come across it yet.
